# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' in Python on edX

Tags: python

```
def adding_report(report = [445, 234]):
    at = input("Choose a report type: 'A' or 'T'")

    while at.lower() == 'a' or 't' == False:
        at = input("Choose a report type: 'A' or 'T' : ")

    while True:
        re = input("print an integer or 'Q' : ")

        if re.isdigit() == True:

            report = report.append(re)

        elif re.startswith('q') == True:
            if at.lower() == 'a' is True:
                print(report)
                print(sum(report))
                break

            elif at.lower() == 't' is True:
                print(sum(report))

                break

            else:
                pass
        elif re.isdigit() == False and re.lower().startswith('q'):
            print('invalid response.')

adding_report(report = [])
```

I am using this code to try to get an adding report, but I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
report = report.append(re)
```

`report.append(re)` actually returns `None`. So what this means is that you're asking python to convert the already present `list` object (`report`) to a  `NoneType`. Thus, it is no longer a `list` and you cannot append anything to it further. What you want to do instead is `report.append(re)`. This will simply append `re` to the already existing list `report` without re-assigning it to `NoneType`.

Answer (score 2):

In this snippet,

```
if re.isdigit() == True:

            report = report.append(re)
```

You just need `report.append(re)`, not `report = report.append(re)`. By assigning `report.append(re)` to `report` you are overwriting the list with nothing as append() has no return value. So `report` variable will be of type `NoneType`.

Comment: thank you very much. Also, I am using a Microsoft Jupyter Notebook for Python 3. I just started coding, and every couple of minutes my notebook gets stuck in a while loop and it never runs. I have to keep opening new notebooks and it is getting annoying. Do you know of any way to fix this.

Comment: @rush2008, you need to ask it as another question with more details about what kind of error you are facing

Answer (score 0):

when you append a list it returns None. See below

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(A.append(4))
  None
>>> print(A)
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> A = A.append(5)
>>> print(A)
  None
```

So when you update the list make sure you just do `report.append(re)` instead of `report = report.append(re)`